# Deserialise JSON from a solar inverter API

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I have JSON data from a Fronius solar inverter. I'm trying to read it into VB.NET classes so I can then work some other magic on it (add to a DB, use the info to control household devices etc).
I've parsed the JSON through some online resource that all say it's ok.
When running my code the classes are coming back as nothing.
Here's the base code for deserializing:

```
Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Temp\JsonCrap.js")
Dim jsonData As String = fileReader.ReadToEnd
fileReader.Close()
Dim myJs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Body)(jsonData)
```

When I expand `myJS`, it shows the data properties from my class but with no values.
JSON is this:

```
{
   "Body" : {
      "Data" : {
         "DAY_PMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "W",
            "Value" : 2013
         },
         "DAY_UACMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "V",
            "Value" : 244.80000000000001
         },
         "DAY_UDCMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "V",
            "Value" : 375.19999999999999
         },
         "TOTAL_PMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "W",
            "Value" : 5568
         },
         "TOTAL_UACMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "V",
            "Value" : 285.5
         },
         "TOTAL_UDCMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "V",
            "Value" : 389.19999999999999
         },
         "YEAR_PMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "W",
            "Value" : 5562
         },
         "YEAR_UACMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "V",
            "Value" : 277.30000000000001
         },
         "YEAR_UDCMAX" : {
            "Unit" : "V",
            "Value" : 375.19999999999999
         }
      }
   },
   "Head" : {
      "RequestArguments" : {
         "DataCollection" : "MinMaxInverterData",
         "DeviceClass" : "Inverter",
         "DeviceId" : "1",
         "Scope" : "Device"
      },
      "Status" : {
         "Code" : 0,
         "Reason" : "",
         "UserMessage" : ""
      },
      "Timestamp" : "2021-07-22T11:34:44+10:00"
   }
}
```

And classes are here:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization

Public Class Body
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="Body")>
    Public Property Data As Data
End Class

Public Class Data
    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="DAY_PMAX")>
    Public Property DAY_PMAX As DAYPMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="DAY_UACMAX")>
    Public Property DAY_UACMAX As DAYUACMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="DAY_UDCMAX")>
    Public Property DAY_UDCMAX As DAYUDCMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="TOTAL_PMAX")>
    Public Property TOTAL_PMAX As TOTALPMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="TOTAL_UACMAX")>
    Public Property TOTAL_UACMAX As TOTALUACMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="TOTAL_UDCMAX")>
    Public Property TOTAL_UDCMAX As TOTALUDCMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="YEAR_PMAX")>
    Public Property YEAR_PMAX As YEARPMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="YEAR_UACMAX")>
    Public Property YEAR_UACMAX As YEARUACMAX

    <JsonProperty(PropertyName:="YEAR_UDCMAX")>
    Public Property YEAR_UDCMAX As YEARUDCMAX
End Class

Public Class DAYPMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class

Public Class DAYUACMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class

Public Class DAYUDCMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class

Public Class TOTALPMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class

Public Class TOTALUACMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class

Public Class TOTALUDCMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class

Public Class YEARPMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Integer
End Class

Public Class YEARUACMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class



Public Class YEARUDCMAX
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class

Public Class RequestArguments
    Public Property DataCollection As String
    Public Property DeviceClass As String
    Public Property DeviceId As String
    Public Property Scope As String
End Class

Public Class Status
    Public Property Code As Integer
    Public Property Reason As String
    Public Property UserMessage As String
End Class

Public Class Head
    Public Property RequestArguments As RequestArguments
    Public Property Status As Status
    Public Property Timestamp As DateTime
End Class

Public Class Example
    Public Property Body As Body
    Public Property Head As Head
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class model is missing the Root object. You can see it if you simplify the JSON structure: `Body` and `Head` are contained in an Object (hence, both are properties of the same Root object).

```
{
   "Body" : {
},
   "Head" : {
   }
}
```

Add a Root object that contains these properties:

```
Public Class FroniusAPIRoot
    Public Property Body As Body
    Public Property Head As Head
End Class
```

I suggest to simplify the model: all those properties of the `Data` class are just one object Type and the JSON object property name is the Key to get the related object.
You can simply use a `Dictionary(Of String, Class)` to handle all the Properties of `Data`.
It's also more flexible, in case those properties can change or the API can return more/different objects, depending on the type of the query.

```
Partial Public Class Body
    Public Property Data As Dictionary(Of String, UnitValues)
End Class

Public Class UnitValues
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class
```

Use the `FroniusAPIRoot` class deserialize your JSON:

```
Dim json = File.ReadAllText("C:\Temp\JsonCrap.js")
Dim froniusData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of FroniusAPIRoot)(json)
```

**Modified class model:**
Note: I'm not sure whether `RequestArguments.DeviceId` should be interpreted as a string or an integer value. It's defined as string in the JSON. Modify as required (Integer, Long).

If you don't like the Dictionary, add back the Data class and all its properties, but use the `UnitValues` class to define the Type (since all can use the same Type).

```
Public Class FroniusAPIRoot
    Public Property Body As Body
    Public Property Head As Head
End Class

Public Class Body
    Public Property Data As Dictionary(Of String, UnitValues)
End Class

Public Class UnitValues
    Public Property Unit As String
    Public Property Value As Double
End Class

Public Class Head
    Public Property RequestArguments As RequestArguments
    Public Property Status As Status
    Public Property Timestamp As DateTimeOffset
End Class

Public Class RequestArguments
    Public Property DataCollection As String
    Public Property DeviceClass As String
    Public Property DeviceId As String
    Public Property Scope As String
End Class

Public Class Status
    Public Property Code As Long
    Public Property Reason As String
    Public Property UserMessage As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Jimi for your detailed and thorough answer, works a treat now. Appreciate your help.